# WSO2 ESB read OperationName property in a mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to read the properties `OperationName` and `To` in my custom mediator written in Java. with this line of code

`(String) context.getProperty("OperationName")`
and
`(String) context.getProperty("To")`

I get `null` as a result. How can I get the correct value? I tried most of the property contexts but I got nothing than `null`.

Comment: Usually this is the way to access these properties, since OperationName and To are the properties in the synapse scope, they should be available in the synapse message context (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath#AccessingPropertieswithXPath-Synapsescope). Could you provide some more info about your scenario? Are you trying to invoke a proxy? What are the mediators used? Is it a multi-tenant environment?

Comment: @ThishaniLucas, This is a standalone environment, no multi-tenancy, and I am trying to access these values from my java code in the custom mediator. The service is simple and hast just this mediator in the inSequence.

Comment: Are you doing this using a class mediator?

Comment: @SaadSahibjan Yess

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the properties 'To' and 'OperationName' are accessible only via the 'get-property' function and not really set in the message context [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/v2.1.7-wso2v111/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/GetPropertyFunction.java#L180). To achieve your requirement, there are two options.

**Option 1**

In your class mediator you can use these lines to extract the To and the OperationName like in the method [[2]](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/v2.1.7-wso2v111/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/GetPropertyFunction.java#L144).

```
String opName = ((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext().getAxisOperation().getName().getLocalPart();
String to = context.getTo().getAddress();
```

PS : Please handle the NPEs.

**Option 2**

In the proxy service or sequence where this class mediator is used, prior to its usage, define two properties like the following.

```
<property expression="get-property('To')" name="To"/>
<property expression="get-property('OperationName')" name="OperationName"/>
```

So then, you can access these properties in the class mediator like the way you mentioned.

```
(String) context.getProperty("OperationName") and (String) context.getProperty("To")
```

Comment: Option 1 was what I needed. Thanks